# Delete Arrow Push Notifications

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

I'm using Arrow to manage Push Notifications. In the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications) there are instructions to send notifications via Arrow API, but there is nothing about how to delete an already sent notification in device.

Anyone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: I think this feature is not yet available, may be it will be included in future.

Comment: This might make a great feature request. Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.